# Another SharePoint query regarding calculation

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calculated-column-formula

Sorry I just need abit of help understanding this:

I have column W, X, Y, Z.

- W is Dates
- X is Rota
- Y is Yes or No
- Z needs to be something, for
  example:

If X is `Rota1` and Y is `Yes`, then Z will be `1`.

Hope someone can help me again. Thank you.

Comment: I see that you edited this 40 minutes ago. Are you still having trouble? I really encourage you to add what the formula you have at this point to your post. Rather than asking us to do a formula for you, give it a try and let us help you fix it.

Answer (score 5):

You may use a **calculate column field for Z**, with **return type Number** where you may add a formula (You may use IF conditions too in the formula) to set value for Z field.
Apply below formula:

```
=IF(AND([X]="Quarter 1",[Y]),"1","-")
```

To know more about calculated column refer

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx
- https://sharepoint.rackspace.com/calculated-columns-tutorial

Comment: Dont just apply the formula. do changes in it as per your requirement.

Comment: I have updated the formula. Check it.

Answer (score 1):

Built your logic in Excel first
all basic functions are the same syntax for Calculated Columns in SharePoint

Here are all the SharePoint Functions available:
https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List